# cannot determine host dpkg architecture

Tags: 16.04, dpkg

I'm getting the following error when trying to build image with Ubuntu 16.04 for raspberrypi3

```
WARNING: arm not found in cputable
| checking dpkg operating system type... linux-gnueabi
| configure: WARNING: linux-gnueabi not found in ostable
| checking dpkg architecture name... configure: error: cannot determine host dpkg architecture
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /root/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-deby-linux-gnueabi/dpkg-utils/1.17.27-r1.1/temp/log.do_configure.11331)
```

Host configuration:

```
4.4.0-96-generic #119-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 12 14:59:54 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

From log file:

checking whether arm-deby-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7ve -marm -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/root/build/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi3 -std=gnu++11 accepts -Wformat-security... no checking whether arm-deby-linux-gnueabi-g++ -march=armv7ve -marm -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 --sysroot=/root/build/tmp/sysroots/raspberrypi3 -std=gnu++11 accepts -Wpointer-arith...

dpkg version: 1.18.4

I'm using meta-debian layer(github.com/meta-debian/meta-debian) that is intended to build ubuntu based images for rpi3

Any recommendations to fix this!!

Comment: How *Exactly* are you trying to build the image? What's the content of the log file mentioned in the error message (`/root/build/tmp/work/cortexa7hf-neon-vfpv4-deby-linux-gnueabi/dpkg-utils/1.17.27-r1.1/temp/log.do_configure.11331`)?

Comment: I'm using meta-debian layer(https://github.com/meta-debian/meta-debian) that is intended to build ubuntu based images for rpi3

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there; alternatively you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.